# Select data from single table using Self join

Tags: subquery

I have requirement to select a data from single table. The requirement is as follows
Select data from table which has one value but not another.
for e.g
I want to select distinct ID which has value 1 but not value 8 present. For for above e.g the desired o/p should be

```
ID      Value
123     1
123     8
234     8
456     1
876     5
876     1
765     8
765     5
```

O/p
ID

```
456
876
```

Also my table contains 500K record so query should be able to execute with good performance
Any help regarding it as i am stuck.

Comment: Yes i tried but didnt post it because i thought i am way off. Appreciate your reponse but i posted it after trying.   select  a.id from a.tableone a, (select c.id, count(1)from tableone c group by c.id having count(1) > 1)b 
where a.id = b.id and  a.id = 1 and a.id <> 8

Comment: Why does it have to be a self join?

Comment: As i need to match data within same table and depending on it group. I may be wrong. If you suggest any approach i can try myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how i got it to work:

```
create table tableone (id int, value int)
insert into tableone values (123,     1);
insert into tableone values (123,     8);
insert into tableone values (234,     8);
insert into tableone values (456,     1);
insert into tableone values (876,     5);
insert into tableone values (876,     1);
insert into tableone values (765,     8);
insert into tableone values (765,     5);
Select a.*
from tableone a
left join tableone X on a.id = x.id and x.value = 8
Where a.value = 1
and X.id is null
drop table tableone
```

Comment: Hi John, Thank you for the help it worked. I have miles to go in SQL queries.

Comment: take it one step at a time. Lots of research and patience ;-)

Comment: You should not even need the subquery.

Comment: @jkavalik you're right... fixed the query.

Answer (score 0):

[except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)

```
select id from from table where value = 1 
except 
select id from from table where value = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try a conditional aggregate:

```
select id
from table
where value in (1,8)   -- 1 or 8
group by id
having sum(case when value = 8 then 1 else 0 end) = 0 -- only 1, no 8
```

or a NOT EXISTS:

```
select id
from table as t1
where value = 1  -- 1
and not exists   -- but no 8
 ( select * 
   from table as t2
   where t1.id = t2.id
   and t2.value = 8 
 )
```

Which on is more efficient depends on your actual data and existing indexes...

Comment: Hi Thank for the response. I have soo many different queries to address my issue. This forum is awesum. I have just started writing SQL queries and all this input will help me.